# module scoped fixture is getting called for every test functions

Tags: python, pytest

pytest is calling module-level fixture for every test function
expected is fixture should be called only once per module

```
#content of test_fin.py
import pytest
import time
import logging


@pytest.fixture
def do_setup_tear(scope="module"):
    logging.getLogger().info('doing setup stuff if needed')
    yield None
    logging.getLogger().info('teardown')


def test_do_this():
    time.sleep(5) 
    assert True

def test_do_that(do_setup_tear):
    time.sleep(5)
    assert True

def test_do_thing(do_setup_tear):
    time.sleep(5) 
    assert True
```

actual result:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-5.2.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\blabla\tests, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: allure-pytest-2.8.6
collected 3 items

test_fin.py::test_do_this PASSED                                         [ 33%]
test_fin.py::test_do_that
------------------------------- live log setup --------------------------------
2019-10-25 12:12:36 INFO doing setup stuff if needed
PASSED                                                                   [ 66%]
------------------------------ live log teardown ------------------------------
2019-10-25 12:12:41 INFO teardown

test_fin.py::test_do_thing
------------------------------- live log setup --------------------------------
2019-10-25 12:12:41 INFO doing setup stuff if needed
PASSED                                                                   [100%]
------------------------------ live log teardown ------------------------------
2019-10-25 12:12:46 INFO teardown


============================= 3 passed in 15.06s ==============================
```

Am I missing something here. if i modify `scope="module"` to `scope="function" i do get same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small mistake in how you are defining the fixture scope. Right now, you are passing the scope as an argument to the fixture function. It should be used on the `@pytest.fixture` line.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def do_setup_tear():
    logging.getLogger().info('doing setup stuff if needed')
    yield None
    logging.getLogger().info('teardown')
```

> if i modify scope="module" to scope="function" i do get same output

This is because right now the fixture scope is `function` which is the default unless specified by the user.